# Universal TList<AnyClass> Emptifier. Is it possible?

Tags: delphi, generics, tlist

I often use extenders of TList: `TList<SomeClass1>`, `TList<SomeClass2>` etc.

Almost every time there's a need to empty them, deleting all the objects they store.

I do it by writing a specific procedure for every specific TList. For example:

```
while Dirs.Count > 0 do
begin
    Dirs.Items[0].Free;
    Dirs.Delete(0);
end;
```

Is there a way to code a universal procedure? Something like this:

```
procedure EmptyAList(_List : TClass; _Object : TClass);
begin
     _Object(_List.Items[0]).Free;
     _List.Delete(0);
end;
```

Or anything of the kind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `TObjectList<T>` instead of `TList<T>`. `TObjectList<T>` is a `TList<T>` descendant that owns and destroys stored objects by default.

All you have to do is make sure its `OwnsObjects` property is true (it is by default), and then you can call its `Clear()` method to automatically free all of the containing objects.  For example:

```
Dirs: TObjectList<SomeClass>;
...
Dirs.Add(SomeObject);
...
Dirs.Clear;
```

[`TObjectList<T>` documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList)